# Can't write image data to path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, intervention

for some reason i can't save pictures with the intervention tool. I have done this before, and i follow the same thing here, but now it's not being saved. The error im getting is:

```
NotWritableException in Image.php line 143:
Can't write image data to path (static/photos/1481902023.jpg)
```

here is my store function in the controller:

```
         $this->validate($request, array(
         'title'=>'required|max:255',
         'slug'=>'required|min:3|max:255|unique:posts',
         'body'=>'required',
         'img'=>'image',
         'desc'=>'max:255'
        ));

    $post=new Post;
    $post->title=$request->title;
    $post->slug=$request->slug;
    $post->body=$request->body;
    $post->desc = $request->desc;
    if($request->hasFile('img')){
        $image=$request->file('img');
        $imageName=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location='static/photos/'.$imageName;
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $post->image=$imageName;
    }

    $post->save();
    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
    $post->categories()->sync($request->categories, false);
    /*Session::flash('success', 'The Post Has been published!');*/
    return redirect()->route('slug', $post->slug);
```

this should work like this exactly, but when i saw it did not work for some reason, i tried also the and it's not working too.

```
public_path()
```

the folder itself(static) is in the root directory of the project.

the Form view for the upload is this:

{{csrf_field()}}

```
        <div class="{{$errors->has('img')?'has-error':''}}">
         <label class="label" for="img">Upload picture</label>
           <div>
        <input type="file" name="img" id="img" class="input" multiple="multiple">
                </div>
             </div>
```

In addition to all this, i have also checked the permission to that folder(and sub folders), and even ran the command

```
icacls "C:\Users\GabMic\b\static" /grant GabMic:F
```

What am i missing here? Ps, im using the latest version of laravel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure, you've given 777 permissions to upload path directory!

Comment: it's just the permission of your folder

Comment: did you try wrapping your location to `public_path` function?

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi this is in local development, not in a server right now.

Comment: @NewbeeDev, The permission are correct.

Comment: @GrowingDev Doesn't matter if its in local, 777 will still be required...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. First declare your path and then verify if the folder exists or not.

```
if($request->hasFile('img')){
    $image=$request->file('img');
    $path = base_path("static/photos/");
    File::exists($path) or File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
    $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path . time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
}
```

Comment: in your code you had the path declared just like `static/photos/`. but where is that folder located in relation to your public folder or base app folder?

Comment: its in the same level as public

Comment: ` $path = base_path("static/photos/");` try the above code with this line

Comment: The `File` facade is from laravel or intervention? should i import something?

Comment: sorry, the File Facade is from Illuminate. add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
$location='../public/static/photos/'.$imageName;
```

or

```
$location='../storage/static/photos/'.$imageName;
        Image::make($image)->save($location);
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to S.O. I'm not sure if using a relative path in Laravel is good practice. Anyway, the OP already tried using absolute paths and it didn't work. Finally, could you please add some details on why this solution should work?

Comment: Welcome. You are right, it is not good practice but I couldn't save image other  way. I don't have clear answer. I think object "Image" tries to save in the vendor directory.